# contextmenu on an image with rotatetransform breaks layout

Tags: windows-phone

I want to attach a context menu to an image that is rotated (for example by 90 degrees).
It works, but when the context menu appears, the image shifts to the right. Sometimes it goes almost completely off-screen sometimes not, depending on its' original position.
The problem:

[image]

And this is how it looks without the context menu:

[image]

The images are of course scaled.
Here is the relevant code that generates this:

```
Canvas _can = new Canvas();
_can.Width = 480;
_can.Height = 260;
Image _resImg = new Image();
BitmapImage bimp = new BitmapImage();
properOrient = 1;
bimp = GetImageFromIsolatedStorage("new" + step.ToString() + ".jpg");
_resImg.Source = bimp;
_resImg.Height = 260;
_resImg.Width = 260;
_resImg.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
RotateTransform _rT = new RotateTransform();
_rT.Angle = 0;
if (properOrient == 6)
   _rT.Angle = 90;
if (properOrient == 3)
   _rT.Angle = 180;
_rT.CenterX = 130;
_rT.CenterY = 130;
_resImg.RenderTransform = _rT;
_resImg.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
ContextMenu _cms = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem _mitm = new MenuItem() {
   Header = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("ApplicationBarDelete", AppResources.Culture),
   Tag = "delete"
};
_cms.Items.Add(_mitm);
ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(_resImg, _cms);
_can.Children.Add(_resImg);
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this?
If the rotation angle is set to 0, the problem still occurs.
If the rotateTransform is not applied, everything works like it should.
The device is an HTC 8s, as updates as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the "zoom out" feature of the context menu.
It appears to simply remove some of the transformations that are applied to basically any element. I have not found any other workaround, except disabling the zoom, with IsZoomEnabled = false in either the XAML or in code.

I hope it helps someone else!